# Visualising multi-layer image in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, image, graphics

My data structure has two fields:

```
* BackgroundImage (of type Bitmap/Image)
* Points (of type Point2D [])
```

My use case is as follows: a user can load an image into the app. After the image appears on user's screen, they might add points to it (by clicking a mouse button). The points should be visualized on the top of the image, but a user should be albe to reposition them if needed (e.g. drag'n'drop).

At the moment I solve the problem by doing the following every time the user adds / moves a point:
* clone the BackgroundImage
* draw all the points on the cloned image (using System.Drawing.Graphics)
* return the cloned image with the points (expose it as a property and bind to Image in WPF).

The time performance of this solution is ok, however it consumes a lot of memory, as everytime I end up copying whole image. I'm wondering if there's a better way of doing this (e.g. by using layers - then my BackgroundImage remains the same all the time while I keep modifying only the top layer).

My code is quite long, but if it's needed just let me know and I'll post it.

Comment: Depending on the actual scenario (number of points, size of image) it could be better to place the points in a panel (canvas) which is displayed on top of the image.

Comment: Number of points: ~30. Size of image: depending on user's resources (basically should be able to load anything they have on their hard drive). I'll give a shot to your hint shortly.

Comment: OK - I used Canvas + ItemsControl like this:

<Grid>
<Image Source = .../>
<ItemsControl ...>
....
</ItemsControl>
</Grid>

But there's a problem while resizing my window - the image scales well, which is not true for canvas. Is there a way of keeping them in sync (i.e. to bind Canvas position / scale / size to Image) ?

Comment: to scale multiple elements equally, you can put them all in a grid and this grid in a Viewbox. The Viewbox will then handle the scaling.

Comment: I've given it only a quick try (missing time, sorry) and it looks promissing so far. I'm planning to look into the solution more carefully soon.
Before that - It would be also nice to be able to zoom selected parts of an image (with the points of course). I've tested a manual implementation using ScaleTransform and works fine, but puts a lot of burden on my shoulders. Is there maybe a better way ?

Comment: not sure how that burden looks like in your implementation. Setting the "scale" properties on a ScaleTransform does not seem very costly to me.

Comment: I meant I had to manually create a variable in my ViewModel to represent the scaling factor, handle the mouse wheel event to modify it, etc. 
OK - I agree it's not that much, but I was curious if there's a way to do this "automagically" (you know how it is: the less code you write - the less you have to maintain).

Comment: OK - I managed to find a solution. Would you mind posting an answer to my question down below, so that I could accept it ?

Comment: I don't think WPF comes with a control that maps the mouse wheel inputs to scrolling. There are probably third party libraries which contain such functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when it comes to memory consumption, there is nothing wrong with the aproach you described as long as you make sure the old instances of the image are not rooted anymore so that the GC can remove them.

However, during the timespans in which the cloned image is modified, occupation of memory might of course be up to double the lowest possible value when not cloning.
To reduce this memory consumption, the movable points can be implemented using UIElements. This could also help keeping the implementation simpler by using WPF hittesting for the "*drag'n'drop*" part.
Since UIElements require more memory than the points in the BitmapImage, the actual savings depend on the ratio of points in the BitmapImage to movable points.

To implement the points using UIElements, place the BitmapImage together with a Canvas in a Panel. Then use the Canvas as a container for the points and set their positions using the attached properties `Canvas.Top` and `Canvas.Left`.
To make the points appear in front of the BitmapImage, set the `Panel.ZIndex` of the Canvas.

But if you are seeing unreasonable memory consumption, you should use a memory profiler to take a closer look at what parts of the Process are actually taking up the space.